# How to specify basic auth per frontend

Tags: traefik

Having read https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/751 and https://github.com/containous/traefik/pull/1147 that are mentioning `traefik.frontend.auth.basic` I'm trying to set basic auth per traefik frontend (not entrypoint).

Neither

```
[frontends.kibana]
backend = "kibana"
    [frontends.kibana.routes.nas]
    rule = "Host:kibana.mydomain.io"
    [frontends.kibana.auth]
    basic = "kibana:$apr1$cHAIJt0o$..."
```

nor

```
[frontends.kibana]
backend = "kibana"
auth.basic = "kibana:$apr1$cHAIJt0o$..."
    [frontends.kibana.routes.nas]
    rule = "Host:kibana.mydomain.io"
```

is working. How can I specify basic auth on frontend level?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like that:

```
[frontends.kibana]
  backend = "kibana"
  basicAuth = ["kibana:$apr1...", "anabik:$apr1..."]
  [frontends.kibana.routes.nas]
    rule = "Host:kibana.mydomain.io"
```

Comment: Very nice. Could I have found out myself?

Comment: how about using lables to configure this? Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: https://docs.traefik.io/v1.7/configuration/backends/docker/#on-containers => `traefik.frontend.auth.basic.users=User:Hash,User:Hash`